# How to work with complex numbers in C without the complex.h library in a non-C99 compliant program?

Tags: c, avr, complex-numbers, adc

I'm trying to create a Discrete Fourier Transform in C for a university project, which is a guitar tuner. The university basically forces us to use CodeVisionAVR because it works well with the ATmega168p they gave us. CVAVR works only in C, and is non-C99 compliant, which means `<complex.h>`, will not work. If i am to create a vector of let's say 800 samples for the guitar tuner, the DFT requires working with complex numbers, respectively with the real and imaginary parts of the input.

This is the code that i'm trying to modify for the task.

```
float read_voltage(unsigned char channel) 
{
    channel &= 0b00000111;
    ADMUX = ADMUX_NOCHANNEL | channel;
    ADCSRA |= 0b01000000; 
    while (ADCSRA & 0b01000000); 
    ADCSRA |= 0b00010000; 
    return (float)(ADCH) * 0.0275;
}

#define M_PI 3.14159265358979323486
#define N 800

float computeDft()
{
    // time and frequency domain data arrays 
    float x[N];    
    float X[N];
    float Xre[N] = {0};
    float Xim[N] = {0}; 
    size_t n = sizeof(x);
    int k;            
    int t;
    int i = 0;   
    while(i<N)
    {
        x[i] = read_voltage(0b00000000);         
        i++;
    }

    for (k = 0; k < n; k++) 
    {  // For each output element
        for (t = 0; t < n; t++) 
        {  // For each input element
            double angle = 2 * M_PI * t * k / n;
            Xre[t] +=  Xre[t] * cos(angle) + Xim[t] * sin(angle);
            Xim[t] += -Xre[t] * sin(angle) + Xim[t] * cos(angle);
        }    
        X[k] = Xre[k] + Xim[k]; 
    }   
    return X[k];
}
```

The problem is that X[k] is actually equal to the complex Xre[k] + jXim[k], not just adding the 2 numbers together.

Comment: You could just write your own functions and structs couldn't you?

Comment: I afraid you have chosen the wrong tool for this task. AVR s do not have enough resources and computing power.

Comment: The university asks of us to use CVAVR, we didn't choose it. They also told us that the code would handle a DFT which i was having a hard time believing.

Comment: (a) You can define your own complex type with `typedef struct { float re, im; } MyComplexType;`. (b) You should probably seek existing DFT implementations rather than writing your own. (c) In the example, you show, there is no need for `Xre` and `Xim` to be arrays. Just use single elements initialized in each iteration on `k`. (d) That’s an O(n^2) DFT implementation. Use something that is O(n log n). (e) Given your processing power limitation, use `float`, not `double`: Change `sin` to `sinf`, change `double` to `float`, append `f` to floating-point constants (use `3.1415926f` for π).

Comment: on AVR uC. tft  is  usually done on inter numbers as floats are fat too expensive . the simple multiplication  takes more than 1900 cycles. division is far more time consuming.

Comment: besides, sin and cos can be calculated at the same time which is far less costly. But this is definitely not a job for the AVR. You need at least a DSP or a CPU for practical purposes. But using fixed-point numbers may help a bit